# Bullet - Jet problem, How to equate horizontal displacement. projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, projectile

A jet is moving hotizontal with speed of 720km/h at height 1960m . when it passes above point on ground at same time bullet is fired from that point with velocity 400m/s I want to know the angle from vertical at which bullet should be fired so that it may hit the plain.
I also want to know the time when it hits the plain.

I assumed that the bullet hits the jet at time 't' at this time 't' the horizontal displacement of bullet and jet will be equal that is equal to 1960m. Now I am stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: You may want to re-ask this question on math.stackexchange.com, but do show some of your work, how far you got, where you are stuck, etc.